# MySql turning - "Select full join" is too high - How to identify the queries causing this

Tags: mysql, optimization

We're trying to manage and tune our MySql.

One alert we're getting in phpMyAdmin is this:

```
Select full joinDocumentation   421     The number of joins that do not use indexes. If this value is not 0, you should carefully check the indexes of your tables.
```

Apparently, there are joins that are not using indexes.  These have run 421 times since rebooting mysql (last reboot was only hours ago).  I've hunted through our code, and run `EXPLAIN` on dozens and dozens queries trying to identify the culprit, but to no success.

Is there a way I can identify the queries that are triggering this alert so I can attempt to change or improve them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your my.cnf, enable the slow queries log, and add the option [log-queries-not-using-indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-queries-not-using-indexes) could give you some clues about the culprits.